# Create Site Permissions to Restricted Read users

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-creation, self-service

I have give all users of my tenant "Restricted Read" permissions on the root site collection so that they cannot create site collections and sub-sites in the tenant. When any such user logs into the sharepoint site, s/he cannot see the SharePoint link in the top bar that navigates to SharePoint page.

However when the user types in the browser window the direct URL:

https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/SharePoint.aspx

s/he can navigate to the page and can see the "Create Site" link at the top. Although s/he cannot create a site, but can still see the option. Am I missing adding/removing any specific permission or this is an expected bahvior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are correct that with even 'Read' permissions users are able to create a new site from this https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx page.  You can switch this off from **SharePoint Admin under Settings**. More details [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-site-creation-in-SharePoint-Online-e72844a3-0171-47c9-befb-e98b23e2dcf9).  I agree it is bit strange behaviour as you probably have noticed that Microsoft has their own of thinking.  Consider it a feature!

If you want to remove **SharePoint button**:

[image]

If you only want to remove the **'Create Site'** link then:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Not sure if I agree with MS approach or design thinking. When the admin option too says "Show the Create Site command to users who have permission to create sites in the location you specify" what does that mean. I assume it was that only authorized users are allowed to create site.

Comment: I agree it is very confusion for admins/IT guys, you can imagine the life with the general users.  I only knew these options because I had to make a change last week at work.